# browser.taskbar.lists.tasks.enabled setting in firefox

Tags: firefox, customization, taskbar

if I open the browser and in about:config set browser.taskbar.lists.tasks.enabled to false

it works and disables the task list in the taskbar.

if I edit the prefs.js I find that the following option

```
user_pref("browser.taskbar.lists.tasks.enabled", false);
```

if I set it to true and start the browser again the task list is still hidden

```
user_pref("browser.taskbar.lists.tasks.enabled", true);
```

So the only way to get it back is to toggle it from about:config. So putting the task list back and editing the prefs.js to add

```
user_pref("browser.taskbar.lists.tasks.enabled", false);
```

doesn't turn off the tasklist either

So the task list is not dependent on the prefs.js at all? It seems to only toggle when done from about:config...

in fact, if I delete the prefs.js altogether and it still remembers the taskbar setting. So where is this particular setting made in windows? Is it in the registry or somewhere else in windows

Answer (score 0):

The Windows JumpList is configured in the registry so as the parameter is toggled, firefox is editing the windows registry hence why adding the param to prefs.js alone doesn't work

I needed it added to prefs.js as I package a lockdown version of Firefox Portable to our customer for use in an application

I found a way to make it work. I added lines to config.js

- Firefox\defaults\pref\config-prefs.js

  pref("general.config.filename", "config.js");
  pref("general.config.obscure_value", 0);
  pref("general.config.sandbox_enabled", false);
- Firefox\config.js

  let wjl = {}; Components.utils.import("resource:///modules/WindowsJumpLists.jsm", wjl);

  wjl.WinTaskbarJumpList._initTaskbar();

  wjl.WinTaskbarJumpList._deleteActiveJumpList();